# Calling Sub From Another Sheet Module

Tags: excel, vba

Using a VBA CommandButton in one sheet that should be able to call another vba module in another sheet.  This VBA is connected within the sheet and not to the workbook. When I run the CommandButton in the first sheet I get the following error.

[image]

```
Public Sub CommandButton3_Click()
   PriceChange.FilterColorToRed
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, try `SheetCodeName.FilterColorToRed`. Where `SheetCodeName` is the sheet code name where the sub exists. The sub must not be `Private`. You better make it `Public`...

Comment: When I add the SheetCodeName I get a compile error: Variable not defined

Comment: @FaneDuru ok changed but still an error

Comment: Do you understand what **sheet code name** means? When you are in VBE and look to the sheets, you can see the sheet code name and the sheet name. If you did not change the sheet name they are the same... In order to find it, go in the respective sheet module and create a test Sub with a single line: `Debug.Print Me.CodeName`. Then, look in Immediate window and copy it. To see Immediate window, being in VBE press `Ctrl + G`. Did you make FilterColorToRed `Public`?

Comment: @FaneDuru What I see in the VBA Project Window in Sheet15(PriceChange).  Is not PriceChange the CodeName?

Comment: No, it is not! It is the sheet name. Look to the left of the name, or do what I suggested above. The string before the parenthesis.

Comment: @FaneDuru Whne i run the sub with "Debug.Print Me.CodeName" I get an error "Invalid use of Me keyword

Comment: Do you know what a **sheet module** is? And how it is different from a **standard module**? I said **go in the respective sheet module and create a test Sub**. "Respective", means the sheet where the Sub to be called exists...

Comment: @FaneDuru Is it not right clicking on sheet14(PriceChange) and insert module? then put the code in and run it?

Comment: What module to insert? You should be on that sheet, then right click on the sheet name, then choose `Wiew Code`... Where does the Sub in discussion exist? Isn't it there?

Comment: @FaneDuru ok, I go into the excel workbook and right click on the sheet name (PriceChange and the click on View Code.  It brings me to the macro and when run it shows Sheet15 in the immediate window

Comment: So, using it I suppose you solved the problem...

Answer (score 1):

### Calling a Procedure in Another Sheet Module

**Recommended**

- Usually, when you want to call a procedure in multiple sheet modules, you will write the procedure in a standard module, e.g. `Module1`. Then you can easily call it in any sheet module with e.g. `FilterColorToRed`. The problem is that it is sometimes not that easy but you can always ask a question about how to do it.

**Info**

- When you open a new worksheet, it is automatically assigned the same generic tab names and code names. If you change the tab name of e.g. `Sheet1` to `Data`, the code name remains `Sheet1`. It is actually a good idea to use code names in your code because when someone changes the tab name, the code will still work correctly.
- In the `VBE`, the tab name is the name in parentheses while the code name is the one not in parentheses. When you see `Sheet15(PriceChange)` in the VBE, `PriceChange` is the tab name, and `Sheet15` is the code name.

**Not Recommended**

- To call a procedure in one sheet module from another module, you need to use the sheet's code name:

  ```
  Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
      Sheet15.FilterColorToRed
  End Sub
  ```
- For the previous to work, you need to make sure that the `FilterColorToRed` procedure is declared as `Public`:

  ```
  Sub FilterColorToRed()
  ' or
  Public Sub FilterColorToRed()
  ```